# Git bash not opening on Win7

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I have been using Git-1.8.3 from a flash drive successfully from both work and at home on win7 machines. Yesterday I noticed that when I try to open git-bash at home, the window flashes open and disappears instantaneously. I don't see an error message. Thinking the file may be corrupted, I tried it at work and it opens normally. Are there any logs that I can check to at least get an error message on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading it again? If that doesn't work can you give the file name and location you are using for git bash?